How can apply animation properties from one shape to another shape in slide
I am working project using PowerPoint VSTO Add-in template using C# and Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint package is using for handle presentation.
Simply I need a solution for apply all animation properties of animated shape to shape2 in slide. Screen shot for the query
enter image description here
we tried code like this
